# Looking for a Monitoring Utility for Nightly./ Continuous integration

Tags: c#, version-control, continuous-integration

In our business, we are looking for a Monitoring Utility that will monitor our Nightly Builds / Continues Build run

Our Build flow includes the following:

> 1. Building the version from the SCM (Source Control Management)
> 2. Build internal installation Kit
> 3. Reverting VMWare server to base snapshots
> 4. Installing our internal Installation kit
> 5. Executing some tests

The Monitoring Utility should provide

> 1. Live notification regarding the progress
> 2. Server Performance Monitoring (Perfmon, Services, Network etc.)
> 3. Graphs / Charts / Statistics

The Live Monitoring tool should:

> 1. Be extendible by adding .NET code plugins
> 2. Preferred to be Open Source based

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few open source and free offerings -

- [CruiseControl .NET](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

Commercial offerings

- [JetBrains TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)